# Elasticsearch replica shard recovery failed, yellow status

Tags: elasticsearch

During an `ElasticSearch` recovery process a primary shard was lost and a replica shard was promoted but after that, when cluster tried to recover this shard 
we got the following exception repeateadly:

```
  RecoverFilesRecoveryException[[my-index][0] Failed to transfer [279]        files with total size of [12.6gb]]; nested: RemoteTransportException[File corruption occured on recovery but checksums are ok]; ]]
```

In addition to that, the recovery of this shard response was:

```
 {
      "id" : 0,
      "type" : "REPLICA",
      "stage" : "INDEX",
      "primary" : false,
...
  "index" : {
        "files" : {
          "total" : 279,
          "reused" : 0,
          "recovered" : 262,
          "percent" : "93.9%"
        },
        "bytes" : {
          "total" : 13630355592,
          "reused" : 0,
          "recovered" : 7036450677,
          "percent" : "51.6%"
        },
```

And after 2 minutes

```
"index" : {
        "files" : {
          "total" : 279,
          "reused" : 0,
          "recovered" : 276,
          "percent" : "98.9%"
        },
        "bytes" : {
          "total" : 13630355592,
          "reused" : 0,
          "recovered" : 10500690274,
          "percent" : "77.0%"
        }
```

The above numbers where up/down for quite some time, but it never really recovered and cluster status remained yellow!

Is there a way to make cluster green again? Perhaps delete this replica somehow?

A dirty solution was to delete the index of the above shard and reindex again.

**ES version: 1.3.1**

Comment: did you restart your cluster?

Comment: No, there are over 10 nodes and it would take time

Comment: It did manage to get a primary eventually? I'm assuming yes, since it is 'yellow'.

Comment: Try disabling compression: `PUT /_cluster/settings
{
"persistent": {
"indices.recovery.compress": false
}
}`, for the indices affected set the replicas to 0: `PUT /index_name/_settings
{
"number_of_replicas": 0
}` then after you see the replicas number actually reached 0, re-set the initial value for number of replicas: `PUT /index_name/_settings
{
"number_of_replicas": 3
}` (3 is just an example).

Comment: @AndreiStefan The dirty solution mentioned in question was used. Your comment about compression looks promising... Next time will be the first solution to try and then the dirty one. Is there any chance this problem will be solved by updating to **ES: 1.3.5**?

Comment: Most likely, yes. In 1.3.1 there is this issue: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/7210 which might be the reason for your problem

Comment: @AndreiStefan The problem appeared again, 3 shards this time were unable to be recovered... It was fixed after disabling compression, thanks!